# ASP.NET/SQL Server Application: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, windows-security

I have a legacy app that I'm doing some maintenance on. It is built with Visual Studio 2008, ASP.NET Web Forms, SQL Server and .NET 3.5. The application uses Forms Authentication backed by the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.

The computers live in two domains.

The domains are:

- Dev PC: companydomain
- Test Server: dev.companydomain
- Dev SQL Server: companydomain

The app runs fine on my development PC and connects to the Dev SQL Server. Everything is in the same domain.

When deployed to the test server for testing, an exception is being thrown when the application connects to the database. The browser runs on Dev PC. The app is logged into using my credentials (companydomain\myusername). The Test Server also connects to the Dev SQL Server.

The error is:

```
Error: SqlException (18456): Procedure:  Line: 65536 State: 1 Message: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
```

I've run a SQL Server Profiler trace and get the following:

```
Audit Login Failed  Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.   .Net SqlClient Data Provider    ANONYMOUS LOGON NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON                    3208    90  2014-02-24 15:40:43.313
```

### Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="Default.aspx" />
</authentication>
<identity impersonate="true">
</identity>

<Connection name="Connection Name" connectionString="Data Source=DatabaseServer;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
```

### IIS Authentication Settings

Settings on the test server.

[image: IIS Authentication Settings]

I've added some logging code that dumps the current user. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` returns the Windows user that has logged into the application. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns **NT AUTHORITY\IUSR**.

What is causing the exception? Why is the identity "anonymous logon" going through to the database connection and not the authenticated user?

Comment: does your connection string have "Integrated security=true"?

Comment: It has `Integrated Security=SSPI;`.

Comment: OK, SSPI sends in the provided username and password to the connection. if there is no username and password, it sends the current  logged in user. does the connection string provide username and password? If there is no username and password, it is trying to use the user running the w3wp.exe service.

Comment: have you changed the settings in the IIS to allow Basic Authentication?

Comment: What have you mentioned in IIS>Website>BasicSettings>Connect As for dev pc and test server?

Comment: Could you please share sqlserver connection string as well

Comment: I've updated the question to include the information you've asked for.

Comment: Sounds like you need to grant Test Server (e.g. dev.companydomain\TestServer$) machine account access to the Dev SQL Server.